# OAuth2 Resource Owner Credentials Flow : how to be sure the given client_id is the official app's one?

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0

I have a REST backend secured with OAuth2 and a mobile application.

I would like to use the Resource Owner Credentials flow to authenticate the user from my mobile application.

Since I must provide a client_id to identify the application which is requesting authentication, how can I prevent a hacker to steal my client_id from my mobile application source code, and how can I revoke it ?

I really would like to know how the official Twitter Android application for example handle this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I just came across it in an unrelated search and saw it was unanswered.

To quote from the [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2),

> The client identifier is not a secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used alone for client authentication.

In other words, the client_id is very similar to a username or email. I certainly wouldn't mind if someone found out my email address, even though that is half of the data required to log in and view my emails. To keep to that idea, the client_secret is a password that should be kept private through guarding your source code and sending `POST` requests only to `HTTPS` endpoints.

As for revoking privileges granted to clients through those credentials, most (if not all) major OAuth providers will allow you to do something through their OAuth portal. To follow your Twitter example, they have a button on the API Keys page to "Regenerate API Keys." If you are the service provider (I say this because you mentioned having permissions to Resource Owner Credentials) and you don't have a public-facing OAuth portal set up, it would be simply a matter of changing the strings in whatever data-store you use server-side, then making the same change in your client source code.

Comment: if there is a restapi request  which is not required login. for example product list ..  which flow  can i use for that? .. thanx for help